# Is it possible to dump a postgresql db and restore it in mysql?

Tags: database, postgresql, mysql, database-backup

I'm trying to get migrate data from a postgre db into mysql (mariaDB) and was wondering if it is possible to restore a db in mysql from a pgsql dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't.

You need to do a `--schema-only` dump and hand-convert the schema, then do a `--data-only --inserts` dump and use a text-processing tool to remove/replace any PostgreSQL-specific code.

Alternately, use an ETL tool like Pentaho Kettle or Talend.

Comment: Although not perfect: http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php did most of the job for me. I have to do some handwork but this is the closest thing to a tool that I can find atm.